# Animation update

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to animate a ball with the use of an event when a timer (timer1) ticks.

This is what I've written so far. The problem is that the ball uppdates one time only, and that i would like the "preivious" ball to disappear each time the "new" ball appears.

```
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {           
        SolidBrush Brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        g.FillEllipse(Brush, 100+a, k, 15, 15);                   
    }

  public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a += 1;
        k += 2;
        if (a >= 1000)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I know it is a basic problem and i know i need to use Invalidate somewhere. I just dont know how.

Comment: Because you are not calling the FillEllipse funcion in the timer, so it takes only the initial value, and doesn't draw it after

Comment: The method you need to use has the name that you used in your question.  Call Invalidate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the timer event, you need to [Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the control so that Windows knows it needs to be repainted.